# Curious behaviour of bitwise AND

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

I was coding and the following code doesn't give the desired output. pos&1 is supposed to return the remainder when pos is divided by 2. When I replace pos&1 by pos%2 everything works just fine. What could be the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int y;
    unsigned long long int pos;
    cin>>y;
    cin>>pos;
    int f=0;
    while(y>0){
        y--;
        if(pos&1==0){
            f=1-f;
        }
        pos=pos/2;
    }
    if(f==1){
        cout<<"blue\n";
    }
    else
    cout<<"red\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Why do you want to write `pos & 1` rather than `pos % 2`?  Obfuscation?

Comment: Note: The original code doesn't compile (`cin` and `cout` were not declared). After adding the missing `#include <iostream>` and using-directive (or using-declarations), compiling with `g++ -Wall` I get `warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of ‘&’ [-Wparentheses]`, which hints that `pos&1==0` really means `pos & (1==0)` (while you want `(pos&1) == 0`). _Always compile with warnings_. (I suggest `-Wextra -Wconversion` in addition to `-Wall`, and `-pedantic-errors` with `-std=c++98`/`-std=c++11`.) Also your `cout<<"red\n";` is not indented.

Comment: This is what happens when you don't reduce your problem to a [testcase](http://sscce.org). You could trivially have confirmed the value of `pos & 1`, but you obfuscated the issue with your `==` and _all_ of the surrounding code. Hopefully your debugging method in future will include _creating a testcase_, and then you won't even have to ask for help. :-) **Divide and conquer, my friend.**

Comment: thanks will take care in future.Help appreciated, everyone! :)@james % has logn complexity while & is maddeningly fast when it has to be used several times.Thats the reason i have used it over here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`1==0` takes more precedence than `pos&1`. Try `if((pos&1)==0){`